# Do kills by healed / boosted teammates count as assists for the Field Medic?

Tags: killing-floor-2

I'm wondering if the Killing Floor 2 Field Medic has a similar mechanic to the Team Fortress 2 medic, where enemies killed by those that are being healed or boosted by the medic count as assists for the medic.

I'm curious because the Field Medic has the 'Focus Injection' ability where teammates shot with healing darts have their damage inflicted temporarily boosted for a few seconds. Do boosted teammates' kills count as assists for the medics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mechanic is something from games like Team Fortress 2.

As far as I know, medic healing has no effect on kills/assists. The skills

- Adrenaline shot
- Focus injection
- Coagulant booster

are merely buffs, and unlike TF2 (etc), do not make assists etc count. Damaging Zeds is the only way to get kills/assists